# tool for checking mysql relations?

Tags: mysql, entity-relationship, workbench

I designed a MYSQL Workbench ERM with many forign keys relations etc.

I noticed that my ERM had some faults, because if I try to generate models automatically with it, it says that I have got some faulty relations.

Now is my question :

Is there any tool for checking these relations or forign keys , because Workbench ERM Designer can't do this, also if I export the script and Import it to a MYSQL Database there is no Error shown